# Pandas23 change the way it treats multindex labels for xticklabels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This fragment of code demonstrates a problem I've encountered having switched from pandas 0.19.2 to 0.23.0:  df.plot() is not correctly converting the multindex to xticklabels.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime 
import numpy as np
import dateutil.parser
import dateutil.parser
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
import platform


print(f"pandas version: {pd.__version__}")
print(f"python version: {platform.python_version()}")
#create the main dataframe
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-1-1', end = '2010-12-31', freq='m')
dt2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2011-1-1', end = '2011-1-10', freq='d')
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dt,dt2], names=['assessment_date', 'contract_date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=mi)
df['foo']=7

df.plot(rot=50)
```

When I originally used this code,  the result looked like:

[image]

But now I use pandas 0.23  and the ticklabels are incorrect

[image]

Not sure why this is occurring, or where to look for the issue.